# Proper implementation of Particle Designer plist emitters in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, particles

I'm confused about how to properly use emitters made in Particle Designer with Retina displays in cocos2d. I have tried using an emitter with a non-hd texture (`fire.png` for example) saved as "`particle.plist`" with and without the texture embedded and I get a warning of some kind either way. I then made another emitter with `fire-hd.png` and the name "`particle-hd.plist`", and I get the same types of warnings, stuff like, `cocos2d: Filename(fire-hd.png) contains -hd suffix. Removing it. See cocos2d issue #1040`

Searching for issue `#1040` yields a little info, but not enough for me to fix this.

A little enlightenment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prepare these files.

- particle.plist (it uses texture 'fire.png' with or without the texture embedded)
- fire-hd.png

CCParticleSystem searches -hd texture file first, then non-hd texture file, and then embedded texture data.

- [hd / retina partcle systems](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/11255)

**EDIT**

"Warning HD file not found" for Particle plist is false warning. You can use CCParticleSystem initWithDictionary method without any warning in this case.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
    pathForResource:@"particle1_traile" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
CCParticleSystem *particle = [[[CCParticleSystemQuad alloc]
    initWithDictionary:dict] autorelease];
```

Comment: @ Kazuki - I tried that and get the warning: `CCFileUtils: Warning HD file not found: particle1_trail-hd.plist`  I have `particle1_traile.plist` and both `fire.png` and `fire-hd.png` in my project.